# How do I make a multi-page GitHub Page Website without using Jekyll?

Tags: github, github-pages

Recently I've made a GitHub Pages website using HTML and CSS and I'm wondering how do I make different pages on it? E.g. have a main page and then a button to take me to a different blog page. If possible I'd like it to stay as a HTML website without using Jekyll. Any help is appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just create the html files for the pages you want and links to each one of them in the index.html file.

Here is a sample project structure:

```
.
├── about.html
├── index.html
└── style.css
```

Then in your index.html file you can add a  navbar that links to your about.html.

Comment: Ok Cool so I just saw this in a tutorial. Another question if I have text in the new page and it has a class so I can configure it in my styling.css file would it work in the other page. E.g. In About.html I do <h1 class="Log">Hello</h1> and in my main CSS styling file I type in .Log { text-align: left; } would it still work?

Comment: Oh wait it would as I just need to add in the same link to the .css file correct?

Comment: Yes, you just have to add the link to the CSS file in the html file and the styling will work. You'll also just need a single CSS file if you want to.